# How to simulate keyboard presses in Scala (shell) script?

Tags: java, scala, shell, keyboard-events, headless

I want to simulate a *key pressed* event in my Scala script. 
(Clarification: it is the same program who shall receive the key pressed event.)

However, I can't instatiate java.awt.Robot.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec scala $0
!#
new java.awt.Robot()
```

leads to

```
java.awt.AWTException: headless environment
        at java.awt.Robot.<init>(Robot.java:94)
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
exec scala $0
!#
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false")
new java.awt.Robot()
```

leads to

```
java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:110)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81)
        at java.awt.Robot.<init>(Robot.java:96)
```

So it looks like Robot not only needs a keyboard, but also a graphical display (and I only have a simple text terminal).

Any idea how to do this (with or without java.awt.Robot)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of program are you trying to send the keyboard presses to?

Comment: I am trying to send the keyboard presses (actually only one press) to the JVM that is running the Scala part of the script. I want to end the blocking of System.in.read(), because (another thread detects that) user input is no longer required.

Comment: Would it not work for you to simply redirect one program's output to the input of the program you're trying to send it to via shell pipe commands?

Comment: Hm. There is only one program. And it is interactive and runs in the Java VM. So you are proposing to have my program to trigger a second program which pipes its input back to my program again? That sounds weird to me. But if you have any Scala code for me, I will try. Or maybe I just did not express myself clearly. The program I want to run my Robot in is the same program which is waiting for user input.